Getting Duplicate class error while adding In-app update dependency in android studio
I am facing issue on implementing  implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0' &  implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0' on my project but am  getting error stating duplicate class found. Below attached is my error log.
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManager found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManagerFactory found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateOptions found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateOptions$Builder found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.testing.FakeAppUpdateManager found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zza found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzaa found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzb found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzc found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzd found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zze found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzf found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzg found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzh found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzi found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzj found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzk found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzl found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzm found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzn found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzo found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzp found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzq found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzr found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzs found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzt found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzu found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzv found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzw found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzx found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzy found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.zzz found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3) and jetified-core-common-2.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3) and jetified-core-common-2.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3) and jetified-core-common-2.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallState found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallStateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.NativeInstallStateUpdateListener found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.model.ActivityResult found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.model.AppUpdateType found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.model.InstallErrorCode found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.model.InstallStatus found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.model.UpdateAvailability found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.model.zza found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.install.zza found in modules jetified-app-update-2.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0) and jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.10.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3) and jetified-core-common-2.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.3)
 
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.


My App gradle looks like this
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'adeum'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Test.Application"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1464
        versionName "11.86.45"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "en"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Test App"
    }


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'abc'
            keyPassword 'abc@123'
            storeFile file('keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'abc@123'
            enableV1Signing = true
            enableV2Signing = true
            enableV3Signing = true
            enableV4Signing = true
        }
        debug {
            keyAlias 'abc'
            keyPassword 'abc@123'
            storeFile file('keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'abc@123'
            enableV1Signing = true
            enableV2Signing = true
            enableV3Signing = true
            enableV4Signing = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.fingo_debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
        release {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
            }

            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.fingo_release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "mode"
    productFlavors {
        //Some data here
    }


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Retrofit Dependencies
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0'

    //Kotlin Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    //viewpagerdotsindicator - carousel
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:3.0.3'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha03"
    //implementation 'com.github.aabhasr1:OtpView:v1.1.2-ktx'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.6.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'

    //notifyvisitors
    implementation 'com.notifyvisitors.notifyvisitors:notifyvisitors:5.3.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1'

    //Navigation graph
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'

    //bottomNavigationView
//    implementation 'com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.6'

    //Navigation graph
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'

    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //viewpager2
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

    //Razorpay
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.26'
    implementation "com.razorpay:razorpay-java:1.4.3"

    //Billdesk
    implementation project(path: ':BillDeskSDK_v2.1.3')

    //seekbar
    implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2'

    //jetpack security
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.1.0-alpha01"

    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"

    //rating bar
    implementation 'com.github.wangda11:AndRatingBar:1.0.5'

    //ktx
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"

    //Facebook
//    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)'

//    //Play Integrity
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.1"


    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0'

    // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
    // So, make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'

    // For Kotlin users also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'
}

and my project gradle look like this
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:3.3.28'  //Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android. - Or any other version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath 'com.appdynamics:appdynamics-gradle-plugin:22.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/notifyvisitors/notifyvisitors" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
I tried some method to hide some dependency packages being called. But am still getting this error. Whenever i sync the project the build is getting built. Get generating apk/aab it is throwing this error.

This is some heavily outdated gradle setup. I tried to get it to sync but gave up after more and more errors crept up. You can try migrating to current gradle and library versions first, it will make it much more easy to troubleshoot. You can start by fixing all the warnings you get in your gradle build.

@Leviathan  so what you suggest?

I suggest the following: "You can try migrating to current gradle and library versions first, it will make it much more easy to troubleshoot. You can start by fixing all the warnings you get in your gradle build."
